# Update statement is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

Can any one suggest the reason why update statement is not working in SQL-SERVER-2008 for the code mentioned below

```
UPDATE [dbo].[CTRL_SECURITY]
SET BI_FIN_FLG = ISNULL(CAF.BI_FIN_FLG,'N'), 
           BI_HR_FLG = ISNULL(CAF.BI_HR_FLG,'N')
FROM dbo.CTRL_APP_FLG AS CAF
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[CTRL_SECURITY] AS CS
      ON CAF.TABLE_COLUMN_VALUE = CAST(CS.ACCOUNT_ID AS VARCHAR(180))
   WHERE ACCOUNT_ID IN(SELECT TABLE_COLUMN_VALUE FROM dbo.CTRL_APP_FLG WHERE TABLE_NAME='DIM_ACCOUNT')
```

Comment: For future reference "not working" isn't a good starting point for getting help from people - try to explain in what *way* things don't work - do you get an error message? (If so, include it) Unexpected results? (If so, include sample data, expected result and actual result, and also explain the expected result)

Comment: Possible need replace UPDATE [dbo].[CTRL_SECURITY] on UPDATE CS

Comment: What error are you receiving, does it simply not update anything?

Answer (score 0):

Change UPDATE [dbo].[CTRL_SECURITY] to UPDATE CS

Comment: Or, for this table, eliminate the alias and refer to [dbo].[CTRL_SECURITY] in full format in all places.